# Integrating react-router-dom v6 into my Ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, react-router-dom, npm-install, ionic5

I have created an Ionic project and have decided that I would like to use `react-router-dom` v6 instead of having to upgrade to it in the future.  I can run the project fine, but when I try to add plugins I get errors and they can't be added. There dependency issues, but I don't know how to solve them.

I create my project with:

`ionic start Test blank --type react --capacitor`

Which gives me a package.json which looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test.e2e": "cypress run",
    "test.unit": "vitest",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.5.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
    "@ionic/react": "^7.0.0",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.3.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^4.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "cypress": "^12.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^4.3.9",
    "vitest": "^0.32.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I want to use `react-router-dom` v6 within my Ionic project, so I run:

`npm install react-router-dom@6`

And this works fine.

After that, my package.json looks like:

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test.e2e": "cypress run",
    "test.unit": "vitest",
    "lint": "eslint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.5.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.6",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.6",
    "@ionic/react": "^7.0.0",
    "@ionic/react-router": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.20",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router": "^5.3.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.17.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.27",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^4.0.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.1",
    "cypress": "^12.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^4.3.9",
    "vitest": "^0.32.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

My app will work fine with the v6 routing, but when I try to install new plugins/packages, I get the following error:

`npm install react-hook-form`

Log files:

```
# npm resolution error report

While resolving: @ionic/react-router@7.5.1
Found: react-router-dom@6.17.0
node_modules/react-router-dom
  react-router-dom@"^6.17.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react-router-dom@"^5.0.1" from @ionic/react-router@7.5.1
node_modules/@ionic/react-router
  @ionic/react-router@"^7.0.0" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: react-router-dom@5.3.4
node_modules/react-router-dom
  peer react-router-dom@"^5.0.1" from @ionic/react-router@7.5.1
  node_modules/@ionic/react-router
    @ionic/react-router@"^7.0.0" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I'm not sure how to fix this, but I expect it is figuring out the right versions to enter in the package.json file and then performing npm install

Thoughts?

Comment: Don't mix `react-router@5.3.4` with `react-router-dom@6`, and from what I can tell, the Ionic router, e.g. `@ionic/react-router` has a peer dependency on `react-router-dom@5.0.1`. Have you tried one of the suggestions NPM suggests to you? This is something that has been on my horizon to do as well, but I haven't delved into the various dependencies I'd need to update. It's a shame that Ionic couples their UI to `react-router-dom` so heavily. I suspect `--legacy-peer-deps` would let `npm install` work, but that may just push issues further down the line, e.g. the Ionic components.

Comment: I'm not sure how to resolve the issue between react-router-dom and react-router...I haven't been able to find anything that would lead me to an appropriate version number to try.  Do you know where I might find the different versions for react-router so I can plug them in and test?

Comment: Well, if you are using `react-router-dom` there's no need to also have `react-router` as a dependency since `react-router-dom` re-exports ***all*** of `react-router`. Mixing versions though will cause import issues. But like I said in the rest of my comment, it appears that `@ionic/react-router` hasn't been updated to work with `react-router-dom@6` yet, so you are basically stuck using RRDv5.

Comment: I'll admit to being too new to both Ionic/React and NPM used in this manner to understand what NPM is trying to tell me to do.  Any specific direction on how I could update the dependencies and solve the errors?  If not, I'll try the legacy option

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. While you *may* be able to forcefully get NPM to install `react-router-dom@6` you'll very likely run into issues when you try to run the app since `@ionic/react-router` is expecting `react-router-dom@5` to be installed. I'm nearly 100% certain there is no way to get RRDv6 to work with the existing Ionic routing version and logic, there's just too much coupling. You could likely drop the `@ionic/react-router` dependency and strictly use RRDv6, but you'll lose access to the Ionic routing components and "native transitions".

Comment: Here's a github [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24177) discussing this very integration. It's from early 2022 and doesn't look promising. It appears the working solution to using `react-router-dom@6` is to ditch the Ionic router.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you very much.  I guess I'll learn v5 and limit myself to useHistory vs. useNavigation for the time being.   I appreciate your guidance.